# Red spots found in Active Dry yeast

Tags: yeast, proofing

I just proofed my active dry yeast in water and sugar. When I came back a few minutes later, i found small red specks in the yeast mixture. I figured that it was just something in the water or something so I dumped the batch and started again, this time carefully checking each ingredient as I put it in. I saw the specks again when I put in the yeast. Does anyone have any idea what it might be? I took some out to look at it closer. It isn't bugs. The yeast isn't expired- I only bought it a week or two ago. I have been storing it in the freezer. Does anyone know what the problem might be?
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds to me like a manufacturing/packaging problem with the yeast.http://redstaryeast.com/science-yeast/manufacturing-yeast/

Answer (score 1):

Red spots in a starter are generally an indication of inedible mold; this has happened to me several times when a split of sourdough starter went bad.  My first thought would be that your yeast is contaminated at the manufacturer.